# Lua: How to use pcall to see if a loop is crashed

Tags: lua

```lua
local test = function()
    local a = {
    'test1',
    'test2',
    }
    for i = 1, 3 do
        print(a[i]) -- this will cause an error, because the table only have 2 values
    end
end
```

if i use test() in a loop is there a way to detect when the loop crash

Comment: It doesn't error because it just returns `nil`

Comment: Bad example. Let’s say it did error because it tried to call a function that didn’t exist

Comment: You need to call pcall with your function `pcall(test)`

Comment: Will Pcall also find errors if it’s like        Yes = function()
local j = false
If I then
—error
End
End

Comment: No because `if l then end` where `l` is `nil` is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop wont crash. It will just print nil.
Although you can use metatables to see if the loop attempted to index with something that doesn't exist:

```lua
local a = {
    'test1',
    'test2',
}

setmetatable(a, {
    __index = function()
       return "Attempt to index with a nil value";
    end
})

for i = 1, 3 do
    print(a[i])
end
```